# How to get the value delta based on the value of the other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get `dataframe` as follows:

```
print(df)
    id    day
    1     1
    2     3
    1     3
    3     5
    2     6
    3     7


# Calculate the time delta of the same id which has a result as follows:

    id    day    day_delta_next    day_delta_prev
    1     1      2                 0
    2     3      3                 0
    1     3      1                 -2
    3     5      2                 0
    2     6      0                 -3
    3     7      0                 -2
    1     4      0                 -1
```

I want to construct 2 columns which are consisted of day delta corresponding to the next one and previous one.
What I thought before was construct a column which is a next day based on the corresponding id and substract these 2 columns to get what I want.
But I am wondering if there is a convenient way.
So if not mind could anyone help me?
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['day_delta_next']=df.groupby('id')['day'].shift(-1).sub(df['day']).fillna(0, downcast='int')
df['day_delta_prev']=df.groupby('id')['day'].shift().sub(df['day']).fillna(0, downcast='int')
print (df)
   id  day  day_delta_next  day_delta_prev
0   1    1               2               0
1   2    3               3               0
2   1    3               1              -2
3   3    5               2               0
4   2    6               0              -3
5   3    7               0              -2
6   1    4               0              -1
```